# AS3 | Move graphics points at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

how to get the graphics points and change the values of its x&y at runtime?

for example:

```
var moveToX:Array = [50, 200];
var moveToY:Array = [0, 0];

var lineToX:Array = [100, 0, 50, 250, 150, 200];
var lineToY:Array = [100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0];

var _points:Array = [];
var linesIndex:int = 0;

var myShape:Shape = new Shape();
myShape.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000, .2);
myShape.graphics.beginFill(0x666666, .1);

for (var i:uint = 0; i< moveToX.length; i++)
{  
    var _point:Point = new Point(moveToX[i], moveToY[i]);
    _points.push(_point);
}

for (var p:uint = 0; p< _points.length; p++)
{
        myShape.graphics.moveTo(_points[p].x, _points[p].y);

        myShape.graphics.lineTo(lineToX[linesIndex], lineToY[linesIndex]);
        myShape.graphics.lineTo(lineToX[linesIndex+1], lineToY[linesIndex+1]);
        myShape.graphics.lineTo(lineToX[linesIndex+2], lineToY[linesIndex+2]);

        linesIndex +=3;
}

myShape.x = 0;
myShape.y = 0;
addChild(myShape);
```

Now I want to change the points values and update the shape at runtime, but what I am looking for is NOT to clear and redraw it again.. I am trying to apply the changes directly to the same shape because it has a lot of points and lines as the update will be every 20 milliseconds..

So can you help please? Thnaks.

Comment: > `Now I want to change the points values and update the shape at runtime, but what I am looking for is NOT to clear and redraw it again`   

but what do you mean on changing point values, if it is not redrawing? 
    
> `update will be every 2 milliseconds.`    really? you want to have 500 fps? Not sure FlashPlayer or any other web player can perform this. Guess, you have some mess in your task understanding, or at least in your explanation –

Comment: yes the update will be every 2 milliseconds but for 2 seconds only :[ ] don't worry..

Comment: <code>but what do you mean on changing point values, if it is not redrawing?</code> do you recreate the movieclip when you want to move the exist one? I want to change the shape points positions only :[ ]

Comment: @Nezarov updating the screen every 2 milliseconds is unrealistic. We are not telling you this because we are worried, we are telling you this because it's not possible.

Comment: I know that but this updating is only for less than 2 seconds, it's working very well for movieclips.. and I want to change the shape at the same time but the problem that the new positions depend on the mouse position..

Comment: it's like enter frame event but it's not! it's timer event.. anyway is it possible to move or change the shape points positions by the code? Thanks.

Comment: :D it's 20 milliseconds not 2 I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just simply move graphic geometry and see it moves on the screen.
There is no magic and when you want to see graphic in different position on the screen you need to redraw it. When you move `MovieClip` by changing `x` or `y` properties the whole its graphics is redrawing still.
If you want to translate all points by the same value the best way to do this is just change position properties of your `Shape` object.